# How do you delete your clash royale account

Tags: ios, clash-royale

How do you delete your clash royale account on iphone? I want to delete all my progress in this game and put it down for good.

You can't contact the company directly on http://supercell.com/en/contact-us/

Comment: ...Uninstall the game?

Comment: nope, if I install it again it contains my account data

Comment: So don't reinstall it.  Nothing can ever prevent you from doing so, no matter how you start.  At the end of the day, this is more a matter of willpower than anything else.

Comment: https://support.supercell.com/clash-mini/en/articles/gdpr-request-deletion-of-your-personal-data.html

Answer (score 7):

As per [Supercell's own support page](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-royale/?p=web&s=my-account&f=can-i-delete-my-account&l=en), you can't delete your account.

> Players can't delete their game accounts. The game servers have no access to any personal or private information about players, and no sensitive information is ever stored by Supercell.

Comment: do you have a contact link so I can tell them my account to remove? or can I ask apple?

Comment: it appears there is an in app contact form I can use, will try it at some point if I succome to tempation

Answer (score -2):

You need to erase you phone completely because it keeps the account information on your phone unless you delete all data on your phone. Or, You could take a separate device(one that has not created a clash royale account before) and create a Clash Royale account and then transfer that to your phone through Game Center and that would do the trick.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty self destructive.